# Why my REST end points are not exposed? though the application runs successfully. Can someone point out my mistake

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am stuck why I can't access the APIs in my Repository.
My 2 Entities
Product.java

```java
package com.udemy.springboot.demo.Entity;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Data
@DynamicUpdate
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long Id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_Id",nullable = false)
    private ProductsCategory category;


    @Column(name = "sku")
    private String sku;;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
 @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
 @Column(name = "unit_price")
    private int unitPrice;
 @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;
 @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;
 @Column(name = "units_in_stock")
    private int unitInStock;


 @Column(name = "date_created")
 @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createDate;

 @Column(name = "last_updated")
 @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date lastDate;


}
```

and my another entities ProductsCategory.java

```java
package com.udemy.springboot.demo.Entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name="productcategory")
@Getter()
@Setter()
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductsCategory {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "product_id")
     private long productId;

    @Column(name = "category_name")
     private int categoryName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "category")
     private Set<Product> allproducts;

}
```

My two Repositories are ProductRepository and ProductCategoryRepository

```java
package com.udemy.springboot.demo.Dao;

import com.udemy.springboot.demo.Entity.ProductsCategory;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "productcategory",path = "productcategory")
public interface ProductCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductsCategory,Long> {
}
```

and

```java
package com.udemy.springboot.demo.Dao;

import com.udemy.springboot.demo.Entity.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface ProductsRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {

}
```

Main.class

```java
package com.udemy.springboot.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Udemy.SpringBoot</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Ecommerce Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and my table have entries.
When my run the application the console looks like this

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.5)

2021-04-26 09:47:10.471  INFO 14628 --- [           main] c.udemy.springboot.demo.DemoApplication  : Starting DemoApplication using Java 11.0.6 on DESKTOP-MTUECVM with PID 14628 (D:\IdeaProjects\Ecom LEVIS\backend\target\classes started by uddeshya1 in D:\IdeaProjects\Ecom LEVIS\backend)
2021-04-26 09:47:10.474  INFO 14628 --- [           main] c.udemy.springboot.demo.DemoApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-26 09:47:11.577  INFO 14628 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-04-26 09:47:11.619  INFO 14628 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 36 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-04-26 09:47:11.969  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-04-26 09:47:11.975  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-26 09:47:11.976  INFO 14628 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
2021-04-26 09:47:12.351  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-26 09:47:12.351  INFO 14628 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1842 ms
2021-04-26 09:47:12.583  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-04-26 09:47:12.614  INFO 14628 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.30.Final
2021-04-26 09:47:12.691  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-04-26 09:47:12.760  INFO 14628 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-04-26 09:47:13.055  INFO 14628 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-04-26 09:47:13.071  INFO 14628 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-04-26 09:47:14.158  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-04-26 09:47:14.165  INFO 14628 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-26 09:47:14.209  WARN 14628 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-04-26 09:47:14.334  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-04-26 09:47:15.987  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2021-04-26 09:47:16.075  INFO 14628 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-04-26 09:47:16.087  INFO 14628 --- [           main] c.udemy.springboot.demo.DemoApplication  : Started DemoApplication in 6.008 seconds (JVM running for 7.699)
2021-04-26 09:47:16.742  INFO 14628 --- [(3)-192.168.0.4] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-26 09:47:16.743  INFO 14628 --- [(3)-192.168.0.4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-26 09:47:16.744  INFO 14628 --- [(3)-192.168.0.4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

please help me.Where I committed wrong.

Comment: Make sure you are having the `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` dependency in your list of dependencies and that it is available at runtime. You also seem to be missing an `@RepositoryRestResource` on your `ProductRepository`. And please include how you are testing this or are you only concluding this due to your startup logs?

Comment: Thank You Sir M.Denium.The issue is now solved. I was missing the dependency I think.

Answer (score -2):

It's because you do not have a **ProductController.java** class annotated with `@RestController`. This file is the entrypoint for all product API request and **NOT your ProductRepository**.

You can do it something like this:

```
// Controller File
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/products", produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE})
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductController {

  private final ProductService productService;

  @GetMapping()
  public ResponseEntity<List<ProductResponseModel>> findAll() {
    List<ProductResponseModel> response = productService.findAll());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, OK);
  }

}


// Service File
@Service
public class ProductService {

  private final ProductRepository productRepository;

  public List<ProductResponseModel> findAll() {
    return productRepository.findAll();
  }

}
```

Comment: The user is using Spring Data REST, which will automatically expose the repositories as rest endpoints and you don't need a separate controller for that.